# Too much slow queries with my multisite

Tags: multisite, mysql

I have about 450 websites on a Wordpress 5 Multisite. The db is about 2GB with 8691 tables. My server is now very slow, I think because of mysql. I also saw many slow queries like this :

```sql
# Query_time: 3.481267  Lock_time: 0.000369  Rows_sent: 203  Rows_examined: 203
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 230724
SET timestamp=1673345916;
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_261_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
...
# Query_time: 4.529533  Lock_time: 0.000052  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 52
SET timestamp=1673345796;
UPDATE `wp_532_options` SET `option_value` = '1' WHERE `option_name` = 'blog_public';
...
# Query_time: 5.066514  Lock_time: 0.000046  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Rows_affected: 1  Bytes_sent: 52
SET timestamp=1673345796;
UPDATE `wp_388_options` SET `option_value` = '' WHERE `option_name` = 'rewrite_rules';
```

How can I find what's wrong ? Is is some plugins ? Or mysql ? Or wordpress core ?

PS : here are [some data about the server config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731133/server-is-slow-even-though-there-are-enough-resources?noredirect=1#comment1387098_731133).

**EDIT 1**
After Rup's first comment here are some numbers :

- There are 88537 UPDATE queries
- There are 42504 SELECT queries

The mysql_slow.log is about two months old.

**EDIT 2**
This is the real memory usage monitoring :
[image: memory usage]
The sudden fall of the curve is due to a hard rebooted I've made. Before reboot there was 43 GiB of cached value, is it normal ?

Comment: The two updates are slow but should be very rare operations. Are you seeing those regularly? They shouldn't happen at all for just general browsing traffic.

Comment: The fetch autoload options ought to be pretty instant though, and you say you've got 57GB RAM so the whole database ought to be more or less straight from memory. Were there updates to the options table at the same time that might have been locking it? There's no reason that one should be slow.

Comment: I'd look for and eliminate any regular updates you're making, particularly to options tables. Find out what they are and track down the offending code. Then probably general MySQL tuning.

Comment: Also the bytes sent looks wrong for the first one too: your autoload options shouldn't be 230K. Look at the output of that query and look for any large values there and either remove them or mark them not autoload, once you've worked out what they're for and where they came from.

Comment: queries can be slow purely because other slow queries happen at the same time slowing down a server over-all. You would be better off checking slowness via plugins and tools such as query monitor which tell you much more actionable data than a raw SQL query and provide context such as what API was used, plugin, arguments, etc

Comment: I'd guess that's normal, yes. Linux is finding the best way to use the memory it's got, and if nothing else wants any it can use it as cache, which will build up over time.